# File (string virtualpath, "image/jpeg" ) does not find the file for my project and works at tutorial just fine

Tags: image, model-view-controller, filenotfoundexception

I am developing a web app with .net core mvc5 using vs2017. I have been trying to send a file to my view by File(string virtualpath, "image/jpeg"). I have worked on it hours thinking, i must be doing something wrong which must be right in front of me. and at the end, i tried the same code on a tutorial code i downloaded, it worked on first trial. and i have the same folder structure for related folder for both projects.
What might be the reason? it is driving me crazy. Does it mean maybe my project is corrupted? or is it maybe some version of some component is off?

I have already tried the same code on same context on another project and it worked so i am very confident it is not the code but maybe some setting.

`public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            return File("~/photos/penguins.jpg", "image/jpeg");
     }`

I am clueless where to look if it is a versioning problem. so please give me some input if not the exact reason and we can delve into this problem together.
cheers,
Atalay

Comment: File not found exception messages usually contain the path to the file that was not found, the very first thing you need to confirm for us is that the file is located at the desired full path, you have shown us the code with the relative path only

Comment: I have been struggling with this for days and everybody mentions about virtual path etc. And all those times I thought it was the project folder not the wwwwroot folder. So the problem was, my picture folder was not in wwwroot folder. I am very new to mvc and have not programmed anything for years. I guess that was a hard lesson to learn. Thanks for the response @Chris-Schaller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, my images were directly under project folder not the "wwwroot" folder . that was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems like yours, what I do is that I use the option "inspect item" of the browsers, if I do not show an image and for "x" reason does not appear the navigator indicates if the problem is path (ie can not find the image on the route that is passed to him)